# Error when executing Google OAuth 2.0 - Address already in use

Tags: java, google-api, google-oauth

I am using google apis to create web application.  I've followed google's guides to get a starting point, so I succeeded on my local PC server.
But when I executing on my webpage,the authentication using oauth2 fails with the following console output:

```
2016-05-21 01:43:31.388:INFO::jetty-6.1.26
2016-05-21 01:43:31.392:WARN::failed SocketConnector@localhost:9809:java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

Some advice me to change the port that localserver's port like
`LocalServerReceiver localReceiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8080).build();`

to

```
LocalServerReceiver localReceiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(9809).build();
```

but it didn't work.

Before I call Google OAuth, 9809 port never used.  netstat

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      877/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3690            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9988/svnserve
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4720/mysqld
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      30168/java  
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      877/sshd    
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*                    LISTEN      30168/java
```

After Call google OAuth, 9809 port are on running.

How can I change my setting? Anyone help me?

Comment: I have exactly same error with you.. any update?